# Error in library(nycflights13) : there is no package called ‘nycflights13’

Tags: r

Is there something broken/ am I doing something wrong? I also tried installing `nycflights13` manually by going to Tools>Install Packages and it seems to be installed fine, but when I go to load it

code error screenshot

[image]

it's giving me an error.

```
install.packages("nycflights13")
library(nycflights13)
library(tidyverse)
```

> Error in library(nycflights13) : there is no package called ‘nycflights13’

Comment: Can you show the exact output when you run `install.packages("nycflights13")`? Please just post the output as text. Images aren't helpful because they aren't searchable. Also, in general, you usually don't put `install.packages()` in the setup chunk. Most Rmarkdown document should not modify the system setup.

Comment: There is no output, but it gets that green bar next to the line instead of the red one.  I am really new to R--coming from Python where it's normal not to get an output unless you ask for one, so I assumed it was the same

Comment: Normally it should print out some message that the package was installed. This seems very odd because I wouldn't expect any problems installing a simple data package. You seem to be running an RMardown document. What if you just run `install.packages("nycflights13")` directly in the R console.

Comment: Ok, when I do it directly in the console it gives me an error.

> install.packages("nycflights13")
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/nycflights13_1.0.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 4504033 bytes (4.3 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 4.3 MB

Comment: Out of curiosity, what error are you getting? That message doesn't look like an error message.

Comment: WARNING: ignoring environment value of R_HOME

and 

Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘nycflights13’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: Well, that's odd. Warnings aren't the same as error and warning shouldn't prevent a package being installed. But I think i saw a message that you were using anaconda. Anaconda makes a right mess of installing R packages. See https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/r-language-pkg-docs/. Try `conda install -c r r-nycflights` at your Terminal (not in R). I'd strongly recommend not using the anaconda version of R and installing it using the official R installers to prevent errors like this.

Comment: Okay! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if the package was in the correct location? In my case this is the directory that keeps packages.

The downloaded binary packages are in
C:\Users\Lilia\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpMzik3E\downloaded_packages

I struggled getting this library, I had to download it directly from CRAN and then extract folder in downloaded_packages folder
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nycflights13/index.html